# Google Sheets: Get all unique names but sometimes there are 2 names in a row

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where I am trying to grab all unique names in Column "presenters". The issue is that sometimes there are 2 or more presenters with a plus symbol in between.

My attempt: `=UNIQUE((QUERY(importrange("1RmRiI-nG_Dy_zWO1XdJfcRIxAhllvMIPj9RdV79xi1g", "data!C2:C"))))`

[Google Sheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RmRiI-nG_Dy_zWO1XdJfcRIxAhllvMIPj9RdV79xi1g/edit#gid=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this formula for your desired result

### Sheets Formula:

```
=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("+", data!C2:C), "+")))))
```

### Result:

[image]

### References:

[UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653?hl=en)

[SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en&sjid=13344915376118529673-AP)

[JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en&sjid=13344915376118529673-AP)

[TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en&sjid=13344915376118529673-AP)